# Is there a name for this cadence - [Tritone Sub of V] - I

Tags: theory, harmony, chord-theory, chord-progressions, cadence

Sometimes I've been going through **[Tritone Sub of V] - I** cadences.  Is there a specific name for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, Db7 - C?

Since you took the tritone substitute of the V (the dominant), this is still a kind of dominant cadence. Specifically, it's a [tritone-substitute dominant cadence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritone_substitution).

Comment: Is 'dominant' cadence another term for 'perfect' or 'authentic' cadence?

Comment: In the context of C major, "Db7" could also be taken as a chromatic modification of vii7. How is it decided, what chord a chord is a substitution for? For me, the use of that cadence to perform the function of V-I in C has the problem that Db sounds like VI of f minor, so the cadence sounds like an imperfect cadence, VI-V, in f minor.

Comment: @RosieF - Db in key C is bii, isn't it? A tritone substitution is the chord whose 3 and 7 notes are the 7 and 3 of the other chord. Both being dominant 7th chords.

Comment: @Tim But in the context of the key of C major, the "Cb" of the "Db7" chord is better spelt as B (natural). Hence I spell the chord's notes as B Db F Ab, and I associate it with vii7, which is B D F A. Now if the chord had been Db maj7, that would be different...

Comment: @Tim and others who have suggested changing *dominant cadence* to *authentic cadence:* One definition of an authentic cadence specifically requires a **V** chord moving to a I. Using the broader term *dominant cadence* allows for the fact that Db7 - C doesn't "look" on its face like a V moving to I. (Of course, if you tweak the definition of *authentic* and/or understand the Db7 as some kind of rootless altered V chord, you could argue that this rises to the level of an authentic cadence. But my answer, as written, avoids these semantic issues.)